# Undefined constant html

Tags: php

I'm trying to make valorize a checkbox through iterating my `$group` variable, but I don't know why I get the error:

> undefined constant html

Perphaps an error with the quote?

```
foreach($group as $service)
{

       var html = '<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" data-id="' + service.id + '" />' + service.name + '</label>';
       $('#provider-services').append(html);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't do this with php? In another class this working

Comment: There's no sane way to do DOM manipulation of the document currently being generated using PHP.

Comment: I agree with the comments but why is this down voted? The OP has clearly explained what he/she wants to achieve, shown the attempt. Mixing up javascript for php is the problem. I believe this as a question isn't worthy of being down voted for that mistake. This is why people come to StackOverFlow, to fix mistakes and find the reason(s) why it didn't function as intended.

Comment: People like Andrey should only be ashamed for the way rude to respond, and I think it has also contributed to downvote. Pass just the desire to program. It's your fault that StackOverflow is becoming increasingly unnecessary. I don't think I will contribute more on this community long as there are people like you. Or changed the mind or actually do something else, because this isn't help but insult and become useless. The funny thing is that it has even got 5 upvote, but we joke?!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing php with jquery (js)

Try with something like this:

```
<?php
foreach($group as $service)
{
    $html = '<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" data-id="' . service['id'] . '" />' . service['name']. '</label>';
?>
    <script>
        $('#provider-services').append(<?php echo $html; ?>);
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: It's still half-javascript. You cannot use `+` for string concatenation. `service.id` is wrong. Echoing inside the JS will get you a raw text which will result in a syntax error when JS is executed. And you probably shouldn't use JS at all, it's likely doable from PHP alone (but it's unclear how the OP generates that part of the DOM).

Comment: Seems that the variable $html contains only the numer, infact when I'll display the content of my provider-services I get this:

<script>
             $('#provider-services').append(14);
</script>